# How to align an image inline with the box containing some text?

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82Lh7hqz/14/embedded/result/) in which I want to align few images (keyboard, computer and handshake) and text inline with the rectangle box (having some text) exactly like [these](https://s29.postimg.org/3tlqlso2v/desktopimage2.png) [images](https://s29.postimg.org/x7hh1dqsn/desktopimage3.png).

I tried making them inline by using display inline-block, display: block,  margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto but still I am unable to replicate it.

The snippets of HTML code which I am using is:

```
.openings {
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
}

.openings .headline-text:before {
    border-top: 1px solid #1072B8;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    content: "";
}

.openings .headline-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #1072B8;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.openings .rectangle {
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
    float: right;
}

.section {
    margin-left: 300px;
    float: left;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #1072B8;
}

.openings .job-opening {
    clear: both;
    height: 150px;
}

.openings {
    height: 1480px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You want `.rectangle`s to stack vertically in the center of screen?

Comment: @fen1x Yes vertically but not completely at the center of a screen, little bit towards the right. The images which I have uploaded will give you little bit idea.

Comment: your image link has privacy error

Comment: If the example image is from an existing website, it probably uses a table layout.

Comment: @MrLister Its not from an existing website, it is just a sample image which I am trying to replicate it in HTML and CSS. Any word on what mistakes I am doing ?